# fgets() causing segmentation fault when reading file

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to use fgets() to read text from a file and I keep getting a segmentation fault. The program reads in the entire file and then after it reads the last line it crashes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *readFile(FILE *);

char *readFile(FILE *file){
    int *outputSize = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*outputSize) = 1024;
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    char *output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(*outputSize));
    *output='\0';
    while(fgets(buf,1024,file)){
        if(strlen(output)+strlen(buf)+1>(*outputSize)){
            printf("REALLOCATING...");
            (*outputSize) *=2;
            output = realloc(output,sizeof(char)*(*outputSize));
        }
        printf("BUFFER SIZE: %d\nBUFFER : %s\n",strlen(buf),buf);
        strcat(output,buf);
        printf("OUTPUT SIZE: %d\nOUTPUT: %s\n",strlen(output),output);

    }
    printf("FREEING...");
    free(outputSize);
    free(buf);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: `char *output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(*outputSize));*output=0`;

Comment: `if(strlen(output)+strlen(buf)+1>(*outputSize)){`

Comment: I don't see how that would help. It makes it through the entire file just fine. But once its finished a segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: I don't see how ignoring good advice would help.  Try it first.

Comment: Also the second suggestion didn't help. I'm currently testing with a small test file that shouldn't even fill the buffer.

Comment: The first suggestion didn't help either.

Comment: `malloc` does not clear the memory, so putting a `'\0'` in the first character guarantees that the first `strcat` will work correctly. If you got lucky and had an initial 0 in `output`, then you won't have noticed the problem. If the last `printf(...,output);` looks right, then the crash isn't in the code you've posted.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY comments do help.  There likely exist other issues.

Comment: Simplify your code.  Get rid of the extra `malloc()/free()` calls.  Instead of `int *outputSize = malloc()...`, just use `int outputSize;` and use the `int` directly.

Comment: Note that because the `printf("FREEING...");` doesn't have a newline `'\n'` you may not see that output before the crash.

Comment: Re-allocating may still not be big enough:  Suggest `if(strlen(output)+strlen(buf)+1>(*outputSize)){` --> `while(strlen(output)+strlen(buf)+1>(*outputSize)){`  although given code's logic, 1 pass _should_ be enough.  Just adding some defensive coding.

Comment: About how _big_ is the file?  Is the size exceeding `INT_MAX`? Note: Ideally the size variable should be type  `size_t` and not `int`.  Of course, checking the return values from your memory allocations is wise too - to insure they are not `NULL`.

Comment: Maybe.... the issue is not here.  But is the unposted calling code.  You did say "after it reads the last line it crashes".  Try `printf("FREEING...");` --> `printf("FREEING...\n");`  (Add \n to flush buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to read, and therefore very hard to debug.  Which is why you're asking for help debugging it.

You don't need to read a file line-by-line when you know you're reading the whole file.  Simplify that code and just read the whole file - that makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot.  (This code even has all error checking in less lines, and IMO is a LOT easier to understand, even without comments or debug statements that tell you what's going on)

```
char *readFile( FILE *file )
{
    struct stat sb;
    if ( !fstat( fileno( file ), &sb ) )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    if ( -1 == fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET ) )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    char *data = malloc( sb.st_size + 1 );
    if ( data == NULL )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    /* this error check might not work in text mode because
       of \r\n translation */
    size_t bytesRead = fread( data, 1, sb.st_size, file );
    if ( bytesRead != sb.st_size )
    {
        free( data );
        return( NULL );
    }

    data[ sb.st_size ] = '\0';
    return( data );
}
```

Header files will need to be updated.

Comment: If the file is opened in text mode, then `sb.st_size` may be more than `bytesRead`.  `sb.st_size` represent the file's true byte size, whereas file input may translate line ending like `"\r\n"` to `"\n"`.

Comment: @chux: Yep.  I missed that.  Arrrgh.  I hate that translation - it makes it impossible to know you got every byte.  Thanks,  I updated the code I posted.